# copying many folders with not inherited permissions

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, access-control-list, robocopy

So we have this folder with hundreds of user folders (not sure what they are used for but there is mostly Desktop, Documents and Favorites). We need to back them up to another disk, but the problem is that the ACL is not inheriting from above folder and all subfolders have permissions only to their owners which are various users. The only way to access those folders is to change owner for example to administrators and then add permissions to them.
I wonder what would be a way to backup such folder structure. Would I really need to change owner on all of the folders and add permissions to whoever runs the robocopy? I am afraid if something could break when owners change from their creators to something else.
Even if that would be the only way to do it, is there some script to do this easily instead of thousands of clicks?

Comment: Do you want to back them up or do you want to move them?

Comment: I don't know why does this matter at all, but I mentioned robocopy - so that means I want to just copy those folders elsewhere

Comment: It matters because by the sound of it these are redirected folders and if you want to move them there's a specific way to do that. Robocopy can be used to move or copy files and folders.

Comment: I am not sure but it doesn't look like redirected folders. They are on E: drive. Redirected folders would be on \\path wouldn't they? How can I check it?

Comment: From the perspective of the redirected folder they'd show a UNC path, but they're stored on a Windows Volume on a server, which has a drive letter. If you're looking at these folders on your file server then you'd be looking at them from the Windows Volume (drive letter) they're stored on. The quickest way to confirm this is to find one of the users who has a folder there and look at the location tab of their Documents folder properties and see where it is.

Comment: finally my colleague checked it - they are not redirected. There is no location tab on the documents folder properties

Answer (score 0):

found a solution:
create a scheduled task which runs as SYSTEM and it can read the files!
The scheduled task runs a CMD file containing robocopy command with /copyall parameter to preseve folder permissions